# JavaScript OOP - Getter that returns member on base

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

I am having some problems implementing getters and setters on my model objects for use in Angular. I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
at User.firstName (http://run.plnkr.co/AvdF2lngjKB76oUe/app.js:35:32)
```

My code:

```
angular.module('getterSetterExample', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      var intObj = { firstName: 'Brian' };
      $scope.user = new User(intObj);
  }]);

function ModelBase(wo) {
  this.wrappedObject = wo;

  this.onPropertyChanged = function(self, propertyName, oldValue, newValue) {
    //alert(self + ", " + propertyName + ", " + oldValue + ", " + newValue);
  }
}

var isDefined = function(value) {
    return typeof value !== 'undefined';
};

User.prototype = new ModelBase();
User.prototype.constructor = User;

function User(wo) {
  ModelBase.call(this, wo);

  this.firstName = function(value) {
    if(isDefined(value))
    {
      var oldValue = this.wrappedObject.firstName;
      this.wrappedObject.firstName = value;
      //onPropertyChanged(this.wrappedObject, 'firstName', oldValue, value);
    }
    else 
    {
      return this.wrappedObject.firstName; //(Line 32)
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I can see, the getter is getting called before wrappedObject is actually set on the base object. What am I missing here? I have included the onPropertyChanged, but commented it out to better show what I am trying to accomplish.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iSAElHU02UBeULZX3WR1)

Comment: This title is misleading

Comment: I would have defined `User` as a service that can be used to get/manipulate a `User`

Comment: @true: Howso? wrappedObject is a member on ModelBase, no?

Comment: You need to set flag for `this` before `firstName` method. Like: `var self = this` then use `self` instead of `this` inside `firstName` method. http://plnkr.co/edit/htJLOyGItYHLa6EO7Vgo?p=preview

Comment: @RahilWazir: That fixes it, thanks. I am slightly puzzles by the usage of 'this' in JavaScript. I will have to read up on that. Please make an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lose context inside `firstName` method. When this method is invoked by Angular, its execution context is global object. You can fix it for example using `Function.prototype.bind` method:

```
function User(wo) {

    ModelBase.call(this, wo);

    this.firstName = function(value) {
        if (isDefined(value)) {
            var oldValue = this.wrappedObject.firstName;
            this.wrappedObject.firstName = value;
            //onPropertyChanged(this.wrappedObject, 'firstName', oldValue, value);
        } else {
            return this.wrappedObject.firstName;
        }
    }.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Is this 'the angular way' though? I'm asking because I feel like this should be coded some other way.

Comment: @JohnSterling Angular itself is JavaScript. Its fine to do this.

Comment: Well, yeah, but that's not what I asked. I wondered if there's a better way to handle this type of stuff in Angular.

Comment: @JohnSterling I'm not sure what you are trying to do with your code, but yes it looks a little awkward from Angular perspective. Don't know why you need this wrapper model constructor at all.

Comment: I'm not the guy who asked the question, just someone who felt all this looked odd.

Comment: @JohnSterling Oh, right. Well it does look odd to me too.

Comment: Just to explain. I want my business logic and validation contained in the model classes. I may move them into the Angular DI container, but so far I have no use for DI in my model. I need the ability to have setters as I need to update a UnitOfWork container. The easiest way to achieve this was to simply wrap the object return by my webservice. That way, I don't get calculated properties on my DTO. I will mark this as an answer, though I so far have chosen the `self = this` approach. I will try this out as well.